# Built-in data types of python

Tags: python, types

These are the main built-in data types that I know in Python:

- Numbers
- Strings
- Lists
- Tuples
- Dictionaries
- Boolean
- Sets

My question is, are integers and float numbers considered to be the same data type? Or are they two separate built-in data types?

Thanks!

Comment: What documentation did you consult to arrive at this list?  What makes you suspect what it says?

Comment: @Norman, I have added a response to your question, and I really hope it helps to clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the python library reference:

> There are four distinct numeric types: plain integers, long integers,
>   floating point numbers, and complex numbers. In addition, Booleans are
>   a subtype of plain integers. Plain integers (also just called
>   integers) are implemented using long in C, which gives them at least
>   32 bits of precision. Long integers have unlimited precision. Floating
>   point numbers are implemented using double in C. All bets on their
>   precision are off unless you happen to know the machine you are
>   working with.

Comment: Since Python3 there are only three distinct numeric types: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html):

> The principal built-in types are numerics, sequences, mappings, classes, instances and exceptions.

**Numeric Types:** `int`, `float`, `complex`

**Sequence Types:** `list`, `tuple`, `range`

**Text Sequence Type:** `str`

**Binary Sequence Types:** `bytes`, `bytearray`, `memoryview`

**Set Types:** `set`, `frozenset`

**Mapping Types:** — `dict`

**Other Built-in Types:**

Modules, Classes and Class Instances, Functions, Methods, Code Objects, Type Objects, the Null Object (`None`), the Ellipsis Object, the NotImplemented Object, Boolean Values (`True` and `False`), Internal Objects.

Answering your question:

*Are integers and float numbers considered to be the same data type?*

There are three distinct numeric types: integers, floating point numbers, and complex numbers. Floating point numbers are usually implemented using double in C.

Probably you are a bit confused because mathematically speaking any number of type `int` and any number of type `float` belong to the set of the real numbers. The [`numbers` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) defines a hierarchy of numeric abstract base classes: `Number`, `Complex`, `Real`, `Rational`, and `Integral`. However, none of the types defined in this module can be instantiated.

You can use these classes to check if a specific number is an instance of them:

```
In[1]: import numbers

In [2]: isinstance(10, numbers.Integral)
Out[2]: True

In [3]: isinstance(10.5, numbers.Integral)
Out[3]: False
```